# Filling multiple columns with nan where row contains

Tags: pandas, nan

Given a df:

```
Name  Alias Value1  Value2  1  2  3...
ABC   a      1         2    3  4  5...
ABC   b      2         2    3  4  5...
ABC   ijk    3         2    3  4  5...
XYZ   a      5         5    1  2  3...
XYZ   ijk    6         4    5  6  7...
```

The condition I want to apply is: **if Alias == ijk then keep columns Name, Alias, Value1 and fill the rest with np.nan**

```
Name  Alias Value1  Value2  1  2  3...
ABC   a      1         2    3  4  5...
ABC   b      2         2    3  4  5...
ABC   ijk    3         
XYZ   a      5         5    1  2  3...
XYZ   ijk    6
```

I can do a np.where statement for columns Values2 and 1,2,3,... but I wonder if there's a better way to do this more efficiently since there are many other columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.loc`+ `isin`

```
df.loc[df.Alias=='ijk',~df.columns.isin(['Name',  'Alias', 'Value1'])]=np.nan
df
Out[480]: 
  Name Alias  Value1  Value2    1    2    3
0  ABC     a       1     2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  ABC     b       2     2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
2  ABC   ijk       3     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  XYZ     a       5     5.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4  XYZ   ijk       6     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: @TylerNG hah , yeah , I really like this Anime:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use straightforward label-based indexing for this:

```
df.loc[df.Alias=='ijk', '1':] = np.nan

  Name Alias  Value1  Value2    1    2    3
0  ABC     a       1       2  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  ABC     b       2       2  3.0  4.0  5.0
2  ABC   ijk       3       2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  XYZ     a       5       5  1.0  2.0  3.0
4  XYZ   ijk       6       4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Here I'm assuming that your columns are strings.  If they're integers, just use `..., 1:]`.

The colon next to `1` says "take this column and everything to the right of it."

Comment: nice and simple!